# Customizing wordpress login page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I need to add some static text in the wordpress login page. How I can do that? I have been searching for long time, but all the tutorials only tell how to overcome the default CSS, but there is no way to change the page layout.
Any hint will be highly appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at wp-login.php?

Comment: yes, but i was wondering if theres some way instead of editing the core files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible!

You don't need to modify core file .You could add this to your theme's functions.php file.

**CODE**

```
function custom_login_message() {
$message = "Welcome to my blog, you need to be registered to see content";
return $message;
}
add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
```

This message would be shown on both login and registration sceen.

[More Info about customizing you login screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following plugins to change the looks of login page:

[Custom Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-login/)

[BM Custom Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bm-custom-login/)